# Flutter AR Camera crash after open WebView page

Tags: android, flutter, camera, augmented-reality, arcore

Anyone can help me, I have a problem like this,
I am working with AR and I use ARcore for it.
Everything is ok until I direct my AR page to WebView page. Then I redirect it to my AR page again but AR camera is not working. it crash with this error message.

How to solve this issue?

> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> com.google.ar.core.Session.nativeUpdate(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> com.google.ar.core.Session.update(Session.java:67)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView.onBeginFrame(SourceFile:98)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.doFrameNoRepost(SourceFile:90)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> com.google.ar.sceneform.SceneView.doFrame(SourceFile:86)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:854)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:785)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1016)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> E/AndroidRuntime(19149):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) I/native
> (19149): logger.h:28 CameraMetrics: OpenCamera: 67.996667ms I/native
> (19149): logger.h:28 CameraMetrics: CreateCaptureSession: 7.34625ms
> I/native  (19149): capture_request_utils.cc:206 Flash:
> ConfigureRequestFlashMode - OFF I/native  (19149): cameras.cc:1314
> Camera 0 changed state CLOSED->OPEN; Camera device opened
> successfully. i=5 I/native  (19149): cameras.cc:1314 Camera 0 changed
> state OPEN->CAPTURING; Started capture session. i=6
> D/OOMEventManagerFK(19149): checkEventAndDumpForJE: 0 I/Process
> (19149): Sending signal. PID: 19149 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device.
> Exited (sigterm)